# SELECT >= month from fb

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table:

```
id | name | date
1  | aaa  | 2013-04-02
2  | bbb  | 2013-04-12
3  | ccc  | 2013-06-03
4  | ddd  | 2013-06-25
5  | eee  | 2013-08-23
6  | fff  | 2013-08-26
7  | ggg  | 2013-09-12
```

and i have parameter $month in PHP. 
For example if $month = 06 then i would like `SELECT` all position where date is >= 2013-**06**-xx.

I can use:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE date LIKE '2013-$month%'
```

and this SELECT month with 06 but i would like also SELECT 08 and 09 from database.
How can i make it?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE date >= '2013-$month-01'
```

Comment: For one, there's no explanation. Second, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Well there's not a whole lot to explain about it, is there?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name
FROM    mytable
WHERE   date >= '2013-01-01' + INTERVAL $month - 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score -2):

Well you could use mysql's MONTH function

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE MONTH(date) >= $month
```

[Reference Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: There are two things wrong with this answer.  First, functions in the where clause slow down production.  Second, disregarding the year will produce incorrect results.